# How to compute PCA "in closed form" in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

It is said in [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html), that

> See also
>
> PCA Principal component analysis is also a latent linear
> variable model which however assumes equal noise variance for each
> feature. This extra assumption makes probabilistic PCA faster as it
> can be computed **in closed form**.

What does it mean? How to take benefit of this form of PCA?

Comment: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/picasso/mats/PCA-Tutorial-Intuition_jp.pdf you're solving for the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix

Comment: I think the doc is just poorly worded.  PCA is always computed in closed form.  I think the doc is trying to contrast PCA with other "latent linear variable models" with which I'm less familiar.

Comment: Okay, what is "closed" here? Just what does it mean?

Comment: Closed form = can be solved in a finite (or reasonable) number of operations, opposite of "computationally hard".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Comment: Algebraic solutions like PCA fall into this category

Comment: In ML, the usual opposite of closed-form approaches are iterative-algorithms (which approximate some solution) like Gradient-descent, CD, Newton-type methods and co.